# Is my proof that the function is continuous "in each variable" correct?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> **Problem.** Let $F:X\times Y\to Z$. We say that $F$ is *continuous in each variable* if,
>
> - for each $y_0\in Y$, the map $h:X\to Z$ defined by $h(x)=F(x,y_0)$ is continuous.
> - for each $x_0\in X$, the map $k:Y\to Z$ defined by $k(y)=F(x_0,y)$ is continuous.
>
> Prove that if $F$ is continuous on $X\times Y$ then $F$ is continuous in each variable.

**Sketch of My Proof**

We observe that $F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}$ is continuous on $X\times \{y_0\}$ (considered as a subspace of $X\times Y$) because if $V$ be open set of $Z$ then, \begin{align}\left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)&=\{(x,y_0)\in X\times \{y_0\}:F(x,y_0)\in V\}\\&=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:F(x,y)\in V\}\cap X\times\{y_0\}\\&=F^{-1}(V)\cap X\times \{y_0\}\end{align}Now since $F^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X\times Y$, we conclude that $\left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X\times \{y_0\}$.

Next we observe that for all open sets $V$ of $Z$ we have,  $$\left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)=h^{-1}(V)\times\{y_0\}$$because,  \begin{align}\left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)&=\{(x,y_0)\in X\times \{y_0\}:F(x,y_0)\in V\}\\&=\{x\in X:F(x,y_0)\in V\}\times \{y_0\}\\&=\{x\in X:h(x)\in V\}\times \{y_0\}\\&=h^{-1}(V)\times\{y_0\}\end{align}Now observe that since $F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}$ is continuous on $X\times \{y_0\}$ and since $V$ is open in $Z$, it follows that $\left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X\times \{y_0\}$. This implies that for all $(x,y_0)\in \left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)$ there exists a basis element $B\times \{y_0\}$ where $B$ is a basis element for the topology on $X$ such that $(x,y_0)\in B\times \{y_0\}\subseteq \left(F{\restriction_{X\times \{y_0\}}}\right)^{-1}(V)$. This implies that for all $x\in h^{-1}(V)$ there exists a basis element $B$ for the topology on $X$ such that $x\in B \subseteq h^{-1}(V)$. Consequently it follows that $h^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

The proof for the function $k$ is similar.

> **Question.** Is my proof correct?

Comment: I think this proof is contrived and very hard to follow. At some points you go to great levels of details and others you just casually mention. I'm not quite sure what is the 'target' level of detail.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Can you point out the places where I just casually mention results and don't give details? I think it will help me to write the post (if possible) in a clearer way.